# Highcharts add min/max Y-axis values to CSV Export file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am looking to add Y-Axis Min & Max values to the exported csv file from a Highstocks graph.
I haven't been able to find a solution to it. Please let me know if there is one. Thanks!

[image: My chart]

[image: Duplicate min/max values]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `getCSV` method and modify returned CSV. For example:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', function(proceed) {
        const csv = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        const yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

        return csv + ';Min: ' + yAxis.min + ' Max: ' + yAxis.max;
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9muv3kpo/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. This seems to be working. 
However, I seem to have stumbled into another issue here. 
The wrapped function seems to be running multiple times and is printing multiple copies of the return statement in the csv file. Just wanted to ask what might be causing this abnormal behaviour?

Comment: Hi @Daniyal Yahya, This can happen if you wrap the function more than once, simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p4dehzu0/ Please make sure that the wrap is added only once.

Comment: I'm wrapping the function only once. 
Using an exact replica of the code snippet you sent above but it's calling the function exactly 4 times. 

Is it possible to edit the csv through the options of a chart? Somewhere around here maybe: 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv

Comment: I am using typescript - react btw. I missed out on this point, thought I'd let you know

Comment: No, it is not possible to do that through the API. Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. You can use this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx as a base to start.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-ku29yh?file=/demo.jsx

This is somewhat, how I've coded my options in highcharts to be.

I have also edited the question and added an image to show what my chart looks like

Comment: I've added the wrap to your code and everything works as expected. Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-w636fu?file=/demo.jsx